# Render an array as list with onClick buttons

Tags: reactjs

I'm new at ReactJs development, and I'm trying to render a list below the buttons I created with mapping my BE of graphQl query. I don't know what I'm doing wrong (the code has a lot of testing on it that I tried to solve the issue, but no success.)

The buttons rendered at getCategories() need to do the render below them using their ID as filter, which I use another function to filter buildFilteredCategoryProducts(categoryParam).

I tried to look on some others questions to solve this but no success. Code below, if need some more info, please let me know!
FYK: I need to do using Class component.

```
            import React, { Fragment } from "react";
            import { getProductsId } from "../services/product";
            import { getCategoriesList } from "../services/categories";
            //import styled from "styled-components";

            class ProductListing extends React.Component {
              constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                  category: { data: { categories: [] } },
                  product: { data: { categories: [] } },
                  filteredProduct: { data: { categories: [] } },
                };
                this.handleEvent = this.handleEvent.bind(this);
              }

              async handleEvent(event) {
                var prodArr = [];
                const testName = event.target.id;
                const testTwo = this.buildFilteredCategoryProducts(testName);
                await this.setState({ filteredProduct: { data: testTwo } });
                this.state.filteredProduct.data.map((item) => {
                  prodArr.push(item.key);
                });
                console.log(prodArr);
                return prodArr;
              }

              async componentDidMount() {
                const categoriesResponse = await getCategoriesList();
                const productsResponse = await getProductsId();
                this.setState({ category: { data: categoriesResponse } });
                this.setState({ product: { data: productsResponse } });
              }

              getCategories() {
                return this.state.category.data.categories.map((element) => {
                  const elName = element.name;
                  return (
                    <button id={elName} key={elName} onClick={this.handleEvent}>
                      {elName.toUpperCase()}
                    </button>
                  );
                });
              }

              buildFilteredCategoryProducts(categoryParam) {
                const filteredCategories = this.state.product.data.categories.filter(
                  (fil) => fil.name === categoryParam
                );
                let categoryProducts = [];
                filteredCategories.forEach((category) => {
                  category.products.forEach((product) => {
                    const categoryProduct = (
                      <div key={product.id}>{`${category.name} ${product.id}`}</div>
                    );
                    categoryProducts.push(categoryProduct);
                  });
                });
                return categoryProducts;
              }

              buildCategoryProducts() {
                const filteredCategories = this.state.product.data.categories;
                let categoryProducts = [];
                filteredCategories.forEach((category) => {
                  category.products.forEach((product) => {
                    const categoryProduct = (
                      <div key={product.id}>{`${category.name} ${product.id}`}</div>
                    );
                    categoryProducts.push(categoryProduct);
                  });
                });
                return categoryProducts;
              }

              buildProductArr() {
                for (let i = 0; i <= this.state.filteredProduct.data.length; i++) {
                  return this.state.filteredProduct.data[i];
                }
              }

              render() {
                return (
                  <Fragment>
                    <div>{this.getCategories()}</div>
                    <div>{this.buildProductArr()}</div>
                  </Fragment>
                );
              }
            }

            export default ProductListing;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this won't necessarily directly solve your problem,
but I will give you some pointers that would definitely improve some of your code and hopefully will strengthen your knowledge regarding how `state` works in React.

So first of all, I see that you tried to use `await` before a certain `setState`.
I understand the confusion, as setting the state in React works like an async function, but it operates differently and using `await` won't really do anything here.

So basically, what we want to do in-order to act upon a change of a certain piece of state, is to use the `componentDidUpdate` function, which automatically runs every time the component re-renders (i.e. - whenever there is a change in the value of the state or props of the component).

- Note: this is different for function components, but that's a different topic.

It should look like this:

```js
componentDidUpdate() {
   // Whatever we want to happen when the component re-renders.
}
```

---

Secondly, and this is implied from the previous point.
Since `setState` acts like an async function, doing `setState` and `console.log(this.state)` right after it, will likely print the value of the previous state snapshot, as the state actually hasn't finished setting by the time the `console.log` runs.

---

Next up, and this is an important one.
Whenever you set the state, you should spread the current state value into it.
Becuase what you're doing right now, is overwriting the value of the state everytime you set it.

Example:

```js
this.setState({
   ...this.state, // adds the entire current value of the state.
   filteredProduct: { // changes only filteredProduct.
      ...filteredProduct, // adds the current value of filteredProduct.
      data: testTwo
   },
});
```

Now obviously if `filteredProduct` doesn't contain any more keys besides `data` then you don't really have to spread it, as the result would be the same.
But IMO it's a good practice to spread it anyway, in-case you add more keys to that object structure at some point, because then you would have to refactor your entire code and fix it accordingly.

---

Final tip, and this one is purely aesthetic becuase React implements a technique called "batching", in-which it tries to combine multiple `setState` calls into one.

But still, instead of this:

```js
this.setState({ category: { data: categoriesResponse } });
this.setState({ product: { data: productsResponse } });
```

You can do this:

```js
this.setState({
   ...this.state,
   category: {
      ...this.state.category,
      data: categoriesResponse,
   }
   product: {
      ...this.state.product,
      data: productsResponse,
   },
})
```

---

---

### Edit:

Forgot to mention two important things.

The first is that `componentDidUpdate` actually has built-in params, which could be useful in many cases.
The params are `prevProps` (props before re-render) and `prevState` (state before re-render).

Can be used like so:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
   if (prevState.text !== this.state.text) {
      // Write logic here.
   }
}
```

---

Secondly, you don't actually have to use `componentDidUpdate` in cases like these, because `setState` actually accepts a second param that is a callback that runs specifically after the state finished updating.

Example:

```js
this.setState({
   ...this.state,
   filteredProduct: { 
      ...this.state.filteredProduct,
      data: testTwo 
   }
}, () => {
   // Whatever we want to do after this setState has finished.
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much Tomleb, this explanation is exactly what i was missing! I solved the issue with States after reading this and for sure it improved my knowledge on states with classes!

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: P.S. I know that it is getting way too long but I've added some stuff I didn't mention at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Thanks again ( never usefull information is too long for me hahaha )! With all that explanation I did a big update/refactor and unlocked next steps of project!